# Increase object quantity if it is exist in array (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for items in cart
and i want to increase item quantity if it is exist in array not to add another item

This is JS Code

```
//add product btn
$('.add-product-btn').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var price = $.number($(this).data('price'));

    //$(this).addClass('disabled');

    var html =
        `<tr>
            <td class="align-middle">${name}</td>
            <td class="align-middle"><input type="number" name="products[${id}][quantity]" data-price="${price}" class="form-control input-sm product-quantity" min="1" value="1"></td>
            <td class="product-price align-middle">${price}</td>               
            <td class="align-middle"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-product-btn" data-id="${id}"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
        `;
        
    $('.order-list').append(html);

    //to calculate total price
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: I suspect you should not add another html line if the product already exists. However, there really is little context to work with, it would be better to provider further informations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would work with an external array to stock currently used IDs and compare it to new additions.

```js
const currentProducts = [];

//add product btn
$('.add-product-btn').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  const name = $(this).data('name');
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  // const price = $.number($(this).data('price'));  // unused for quick debug
  const price = $(this).data('price'); // used for quick debug

  let productAlreadyPresent = false;
  if (currentProducts.includes(id)) {
    productAlreadyPresent = true;
    const inputName = '#quantity-' + id;
    const productQuantity = Number($(inputName).val()) + 1;
    $(inputName).val(productQuantity);
  } else {

    //$(this).addClass('disabled');

    const html =
      `<tr>
            <td class="align-middle">${name}</td>
            <td class="align-middle"><input type="number" id="quantity-${id}" name="products[${id}][quantity]" data-price="${price}" class="form-control input-sm product-quantity" min="1" value="1"></td>
            <td class="product-price align-middle">${price}</td>               
            <td class="align-middle"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-product-btn" data-id="${id}"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
        </tr>
        `;
  $('.order-list').append(html);
  }
  if (!productAlreadyPresent) {
    currentProducts.push(id);
  }

  //to calculate total price
  // calculateTotal();  // unused for quick debug
});
```

```css
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-product-btn" data-name="product1" data-id="123456" data-price="1000">
  Product 1
</button>
<button class="add-product-btn" data-name="product2" data-id="789123" data-price="2000">
  Product 2
</button>
<div class="order-list">

</div>
```

Comment: but i want to multiply the quantity * price on every click on the product button .. i tried this with click event but it not working

Comment: Here is the exact code you requested with price calculation on click and input change in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/alexandresaglier/knr9f4qw/33/ A word of caution however : manipulating data from multiple sources can lead to mistakes. You should rethink your code and manipulate data in a single source and use this source to populate your front-end.